# Utilizar função em outra pasta Golang

Tags: golang

Criei um `pacote` dentro de `$GOPATH/src/github.com/meu-user/meupacote` com um arquivo `meupacote.go` que possui a função `main` e outra pasta com o nome `products`que possui o arquivo `products.go`, neste meu arquivo `products.go` possuo uma função `getBySKU`, como posso usar esta função no meu arquivo principal `meupacote.go`? veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
- meupacote
  - products
    -products.go
  - meupacote.go
```

Estou tentando usa-la diretamente pois esta "dentro do mesmo pacote" e só recebo o erro de que a função `getBySKU` é indefinida, tentei tambem definir a função como "exportavel" com `GetBySKU` e o mesmo erro permanece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro da estrutura que você colocou, você pode definir `products` como sendo um pacote

**products.go**

```
package products
(...)
```

E em meu `meupacote.go` você faz o import pela via usual, mas definindo `meupacote` como sendo raíz de `products`!

**meupacote.go**

```
(...)
import "github.com/meu-user/meupacote/products"
```

Lembrando de definir a função `GetBySKU` como exportável

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou a chegar na solução! obrigado! mas como estou criando no meu `$GOPATH` para importa-lo precisei colocar `import "github.com/meu-user/meu-package/product"

Comment: Verdade! Me esqueci desse detalhe. Já aceitei a edição sugerida pelo Mário Idival que corrige isso